# How to build nested responses in an Apigility driven application with a ZfcBase-DbMapper based model?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, one-to-many, datamapper, laminas-api-tools

I'm developing a RESTful web application -- [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) driven and based on the [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/). For the model layer I'm using the [`ZfcBase`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase) [`DbMapper`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php). The model essentially consists of two entities: `Project` and `Image` (`1:n`) and is currently implemented like this:

```
ProjectCollection extends Paginator
ProjectEntity
ProjectMapper extends AbstractDbMapper
ProjectService implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
ProjectServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
```

The same structure for `Image`.

When the resource (`/projects[/:id]`) is requested, the responsed project entity/entities should contain a list of its/their `Image` entities.

**So, how can/should this `1:n` structure be implemented?**

Subquestions:

1. Does [`DbMapper`] provide some "magic" for retrieving such tree structures "automatically" without to write `JOIN`s (or use an ORM)?
2. Does [`Apigility`] provide some "magic" for building nested responses?

---

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects?page=1"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects?page=1"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "project_1",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "title": "image_1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "title": "image_2"
                    }
                ],
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "project_2",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "title": "image_3"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "title": "image_4"
                    }
                ],
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "page_count": 1,
    "page_size": 25,
    "total_items": 1
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The output I'm currentliy getting is:

**`/projects/:id`**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "...",
    ...
    "_embedded": {
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "project_id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                ...
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/images/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "project_id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                ...
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/images/2"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "project_id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                ...
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/images/3"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/1"
        }
    }
}
```

So it works for one single object. But not for collections, where single items include futher collections:

**`/projects`**

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects?page=1"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects?page=24"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects?page=2"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                ... <-- HERE I WANT TO GET ["images": {...}, {...}, {...}]
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "...",
                ... <-- HERE I WANT TO GET ["images": {...}, {...}, {...}]
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/2"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "...",
                ... <-- HERE I WANT TO GET ["images": {...}, {...}, {...}]
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/3"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "page_count": 24,
    "page_size": 3,
    "total_items": 72
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I edited my code and made a step to the goal.

It could not work, since my **`ProjectService#getProjects()`** was just returning the projects' data from the database, not enriched with the images:

```
public function getProjects() {
    return $this->getMapper()->findAll();
}
```

edited to:

```
public function getProjects() {
    $projects = $this->getMapper()->findAll();
    foreach ($projects as $key => $project) {
        $images = $this->getImageService()->getImagesForProject($project['id']);
        $projects[$key]['images'] = $images;
    }
    return $projects;
}
```

and the **`ProjectMapper#findAll()`**

```
public function findAll() {
    $select = $this->getSelect();
    $adapter = $this->getDbAdapter();
    $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $adapter);
    $collection = new ProjectCollection($paginatorAdapter);
    return $collection;
}
```

edited to:

```
public function findAll() {
    $select = $this->getSelect();
    $adapter = $this->getDbAdapter();
    $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $adapter);
    // @todo Replace the constants with data from the config and request.
    $projects = $paginatorAdapter->getItems(0, 2);
    $projects = $projects->toArray();
    return $projects;
}
```

Now I get the wished output:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                ...
                "_embedded": {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "project_id": "1",
                            "title": "...",
                            ...
                            "_links": {
                                "self": {
                                    "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/images/1"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            ...
                        },
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "...",
                ...
                "_embedded": {
                    "images": [
                        ...
                    ]
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_items": 2
}
```

But it's a little bit crappy solution, isn't it? What I'm actually doing, is: I'm just replacing a part of the Apigility data retrieving functionality... Anyway, I don't like this solution and want to find a better one (an "Apigility conform solution").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution. (Thanks once again @ [poisa](https://github.com/poisa) for his [solution suggestion](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility/issues/90#issuecomment-77708913) on GitHub.) In short, the idea is to enrich the (`projects`) list items with nested (`image`) items lists on the hydration step. I actually don't really like this way, since it's too much model logic on the hydration level for me. But it works. Here we go:

**`/module/Portfolio/config/module.config.php`**

```
return array(
    ...
    'zf-hal' => array(
        'metadata_map' => array(
            ...
            'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectEntity' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'route_name' => 'portfolio.rest.project',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'hydrator' => 'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectHydrator',
            ),
            'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectCollection' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'route_name' => 'portfolio.rest.project',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'is_collection' => true,
            ),
            ...
        ),
    ),
);
```

**`Portfolio\Module`**

```
class Module implements ApigilityProviderInterface {

    ...

    public function getHydratorConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                // V2
                'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectHydrator' => function(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                    $projectHydrator = new ProjectHydrator();
                    $projectHydrator->setImageService($serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Portfolio\V2\Rest\ImageService'));
                    return $projectHydrator;
                }
            ),
        );
    }

    ...

}
```

**`Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectHydrator`**

```
namespace Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project;

use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
use Portfolio\V2\Rest\Image\ImageService;

class ProjectHydrator extends ClassMethods {

    /**
     * @var ImageService
     */
    protected $imageService;

    /**
     * @return ImageService the $imageService
     */
    public function getImageService() {
        return $this->imageService;
    }

    /**
     * @param ImageService $imageService
     */
    public function setImageService(ImageService $imageService) {
        $this->imageService = $imageService;
        return $this;
    }

    /*
     * Doesn't need to be implemented:
     * the ClassMethods#hydrate(...) handle the $data already as wished.
     */
    /*
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object) {
        $object = parent::hydrate($data, $object);
        if ($object->getId() !== null) {
            $images = $this->imageService->getImagesForProject($object->getId());
            $object->setImages($images);
        }
        return $object;
    }
    */

    /**
     * @see \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods::extract()
     */
    public function extract($object) {
        $array = parent::extract($object);
        if ($array['id'] !== null) {
            $images = $this->imageService->getImagesForProject($array['id']);
            $array['images'] = $images;
        }
        return $array;
    }

}
```

**`Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectMapperFactory`**

```
namespace Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ProjectMapperFactory {

    public function __invoke(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager) {
        $mapper = new ProjectMapper();
        $mapper->setDbAdapter($serviceManager->get('PortfolioDbAdapter_V2'));
        $mapper->setEntityPrototype($serviceManager->get('Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectEntity'));
        $projectHydrator = $serviceManager->get('HydratorManager')->get('Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectHydrator');
        $mapper->setHydrator($projectHydrator);
        return $mapper;
    }

}
```

**`Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectMapper`**

```
namespace Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project;

use ZfcBase\Mapper\AbstractDbMapper;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;

class ProjectMapper extends AbstractDbMapper {

    ...

    /**
     * Provides a collection of all the available projects.
     *
     * @return \Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectCollection
     */
    public function findAll() {
        $resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet(
            $this->getHydrator(),
            $this->getEntityPrototype()
        );
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $adapter = $this->getDbAdapter();
        $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $adapter, $resultSetPrototype);
        $collection = new ProjectCollection($paginatorAdapter);
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Provides a project by ID.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectEntity
     */
    public function findById($id) {
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->where(array(
            'id' => $id,
        ));
        $entity = $this->select($select)->current();
        return $entity;
    }

    ...

}
```

As I already said in my post on GitHub, it would be great to get a feedback from someone from the Apigility core team, wheter this solution is "Apigility conform" and, if not, what is a better/"correct" solution.

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same issue, did you got any proper solution so far?

Comment: Hi @JimitShah, it was a proper solution for me. I still don't know, whether there is a better / more elegant one, but at least this one worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with db-mapper, but I think can answer question **2** for you.

If your extracted project resource (an array) has a key `images` that holds an object of type `Hal\Collection` it will automatically extract this collection and render it as you show in your Hal example.

This "magic" happens because `extractEmbeddedCollection` is called in the `renderEntity` method in `Hal.php` [on line 563](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/Plugin/Hal.php#L563).

### EDIT

You write that you want:

```
["images": {...}, {...}, {...}]
```

But what you should actually aim for is this:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "...",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://myproject-api.misc.loc/projects/2"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "images": [ 
            {...}, 
            {...}, 
            {...}
        ]
    }
}
```

How do you extract your objects? Did you register a hydrator in your metadata map?

You should try to return something like this:

```
use ZF\Hal\Collection

...

$images = new Collection($arrayOfImages);

$project['images'] = $images;
```

then it should work (I don't know how else to explain it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've finally got it working -- almost... My entity `Project` has a property images, but it has the type `Zend\Paginator\Paginator`. It works for single objects: that means, `/project/:id` provides a project with its images: `{"id":"1", "title":"foo","_embedded":{"images":[{image1}, {image2}, {image3}]}}`. (That means for me: The variant with `Paginator` as parent class for collections works.) But it doesn't work for `/project` -- when I request a projects list, its items don't contain embedded images lists (see **EDIT**). Do you know, how to get it working too?

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, I'll number the parts of my comment: **1.** `You write that you want ... But what you should actually aim for is ...` -- Exactly, I meaned the correct `HAL` format with `_embedded`. **2.** "Did you register a hydrator in your metadata map? " -- Yes, I'm using the `Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ClassMethods`. **3.** "How do you extract your objects?" -- please take a look a my **EDIT**. **4.** Your collection suggestion: The Problem is, that I cannot iterate through a `ZF\Hal\Collection` and modify its items.