# How to access and manipulate data in Apigility before it is sent to the client?

Tags: php, collections, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm developing an [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) driven application based on the [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/).

Currently I'm sending the data retrieved in the database directly to the client: a request comes in, the `MyResource#fetch(...)` or `MyResource#fetchAll(...)` gets triggered and calls an appropriate method on `MyService` class, that calls `MyMapper` to retireve the data with its methods like `findFooByBar(...)`.

**Now I'd like to process the data, before the response is sent. How can I do that?**

---

The [Apigility ZF HAL documentation](https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-hal) shows, how to access the entity data between it has been retrieved and sent to the client. Well I tried this out. It's ugly and to much code for such task. And... it doesn't work. I want however post here my attept:

```
namespace Portfolio;

...

class Module implements ApigilityProviderInterface {

    private $serviceManager;

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event) {
        $application = $event->getTarget();
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');
        $hal = $viewHelperManager->get('Hal');
        $hal->getEventManager()->attach('renderEntity', array($this, 'onRenderEntity'));
        $hal->getEventManager()->attach('renderCollection', array($this, 'onRenderCollection'));
    }

    public function onRenderEntity($event) {
        $entity = $event->getParam('entity');
        if ($entity->entity instanceof ProjectEntity) {
            $projectEntity = $entity->entity;
            $imageCollection = $this->tempCreateimagesForProject(
                $event, $entity->entity->getId()
            );
            $projectEntity->setImages($imageCollection);
            $event->setParam('entity', $projectEntity);
        }
    }

    public function onRenderCollection($event) {
        $collection = $event->getParam('collection');
        $projectCollection = $collection->getCollection();
        if ($projectCollection instanceof ProjectCollection) {
            foreach ($projectCollection as $key => $projectItem) {
                $tempProject = $projectCollection->getItem($key);
                $tempProject->append(
                    ['images' => $this->tempCreateimagesForProject($tempProject->offsetGet('id'))]
                );
                $projectCollection->getItem($key)->offsetSet($key, $tempProject);
            }
        }
    }

    private function tempCreateimagesForProject(Event $event, $projectId) {
        $imageService = $this->serviceManager->get('Portfolio\V2\Rest\ImageService');
        $imageCollection = $imageService->getImagesForProject($projectId);
        return $imageCollection;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is handling the data in the Hydrator. So we write a custom Hydrator class and enrich the items with nested objects and lists in it. It can look like this:

**`Portfolio\V2\Rest\Project\ProjectHydrator`**

```
...

class ProjectHydrator extends ClassMethods {

    /**
     * @var ImageService
     */
    protected $imageService;

    ...

    /*
     * Doesn't need to be implemented:
     * the ClassMethods#hydrate(...) handle the $data already as wished.
     */
    /*
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object) {
        $object = parent::hydrate($data, $object);
        if ($object->getId() !== null) {
            $images = $this->imageService->getImagesForProject($object->getId());
            $object->setImages($images);
        }
        return $object;
    }
    */

    /**
     * @see \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods::extract()
     */
    public function extract($object) {
        $array = parent::extract($object);
        if ($array['id'] !== null) {
            $images = $this->imageService->getImagesForProject($array['id']);
            $array['images'] = $images;
        }
        return $array;
    }

}
```

It's not a nice solution, since then a part of the model / data retrieving logic gets moved to the hydrator. But it works. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370188/2019043) is shown an implementation of this approach and [here](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility/issues/90) is a discussion to this topic on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `renderEntity` and `renderCollection` events is not the correct spot to add this kind of resource specific logic. It is more suitable for more general changes or incidental customization.

You can add this logic to your resource listeners. So in your `fetch` and `fetchAll` methods in your `MyResource` class you can add the custom code you currently added in these `onRenderEntity` and `onRenderCollection` methods.

So something like this:

```
class MyResource extends AbstractResourceListener
{
    /**
     * Your image service dependency
     */
    protected $imageService;

    /* ... */

    public function fetch($id)
    {
        $project = $this->projectMapper->fetch($id);

        $imageCollection = $this->imageService->getImagesForProject($project);

        $project->setImages($imageCollection);
        return $project;
    }

    /* ... */

    public function fetchAll($params = array())
    {
        $projects = $this->projectMapper->fetchAll();

        foreach ($projects as $key => $project) {
            $imageCollection = $this->imageService->getImagesForProject($project);
            $project->setImages($imageCollection);
        }

        return $projects;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! `public function fetch($id) { $projectMapper = $this->getServiceManager()->get('...\ProjectMapper'); $project = $projectMapper->findById($id); $imageService = $this->getServiceManager()->get('...\ImageService'); $imageCollection = $imageService->getImagesForProject($project->getId()); $project->setImages($imageCollection); return $project; }` within the `ProjectResource` class returns the wished output (single project with `__embedded` images).

Comment: So, it works for single **entities**. But not for **collections**. Collections are `Zend\Paginator\Paginator` objects. `public function fetchAll(...) { ... $projects = $projectMapper->findAll(); foreach ($projects as $key => $project) { $imageCollection = ....; $project['images'] = $imageCollection; } return $projects; }` returns projects without images, since we are only manipulating _copies_ of `Project` items in the loop. `$projects[$key]->setImages(...)` also doesn't help, because `projects` is a `Paginator`, not an `array`/`ArrayObject`.

Comment: That's why I was looking for a workaround for this problem and also tried this over events. You are right, it cannot be a good solution, even if it would work. But for a "correct" solution over the `Resource` class we need writing access to the data of the `Collection` (that `extends` `Zend\Paginator\Paginator`). (How) Can its data be accessed and manipulated?

Comment: @automatix Since I am using doctrine for database abstraction I don't have any issues fetching my collections embedded in my entities. You should try to fetch join your collections in your queries. Not sure how you achieve this with your database mappers. You can also use custom hydrators to get the collections during extraction. But this seems not correct if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `ClassMethods` Hydrator and your `Collection` extends `\Zend\Paginator\Paginator` a good solution without losing the Collection's consistency and not changing anybody's code is to overwrite your **getCurrentItems()** method.

```
public class MyResourceCollection // most likely extends Paginator
{
    public function getCurrentItems()
    {
        // getting the original items
        $items = parent::getCurrentItems();
        // as we work with objects $item will be an object
        // when working with objects we use references to them not clones of objects
        // so changes to $item are also present in the collection
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $oldSomething = $item->getSomething();
            $item->setSomething('['.$oldSomething.']');
        }
        // $items are now changed, return them
        return $items;
    }
}
```

I have named the key `something` not to get confused with the `getValue` method from other places.

This makes the `something` value look like `[something]`.